# Insert multiple data from subquery into another table in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have table alpha with two columns

```
id   school_name
```

I have another table beta which has around 600 rows of data with following columns

```
id  school_name    school_state school_city
```

now i want to select school_name from beta and insert it into alpha

something like

```
insert into alpha (school_name) values(select school_name from beta )
```

but for all data ,I know it can be done with procedures but pgsql doesn't support procedures unlike mysql ,so how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax does not use a `VALUES` clause.  Fix your syntax slightly, and your query should work:

```
INSERT INTO alpha (school_name)
SELECT school_name
FROM beta;
```